# JCEF - access browser window object

Tags: java, chromium-embedded

I need to access the browser window object to assign some objects and functions to it. I have read that it may be possible on `onContextCreated` call but I even don't know on which object it is called and how to access this object. I read https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=12367 but those 'fancy' links don't help...

Also, I fetched both [JCEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/src/71141140e1ef3ca71704e83915ddd2b7ec8272d8/java/org/cef/browser/?at=master) and [Pandomium](https://github.com/dzikoysk/Pandomium), which wraps jcef natives... but didn't found any hint in any of them (searched by calls of `onContextCreated`).
I have only found `CefMessageRouter`, but it seems to provide only basic function calls and callbacks (I also need to pass an object which contains function also), which not exactly makes me happy.

To say more, I know that assigning values may be possible with `CefV8Value`... but didn't found implementation (and even declaration) of it in java files.

Maybe it is possible to hack this like pass name of the existing function and then allow js to find this one in the scope, but the problem is I would not like to not give my web app too much knowledge about being embedded...

I appreciate any help.